Loading Google Fonts with preconnect
I am loading some Google Fonts on my page:
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Josefin+Sans:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Metal+Mania&family=Poppins:wght@300;600;700&family=Raleway:wght@300;400&display=swap">           

For curiousity I was passing the url's https://fonts.googleapis.com and https://fonts.gstatic.com into my Chrome browser but the came both with an 404 error page.
Is this normal or am i missing something?

These URLs doesn't have any index document that's all - no problem. But testing the actual CSS query URLs is a good idea especially if your manually changing the query. For instance https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;1200 would return an error as there is no result for this query and the API is quite unforgiving
